# Could not autowire field using @Autowired annotation

Tags: spring

I tried to autowire the fields from property file. I just keep the property file in class path.

```
@Autowired
public BlankDisk(@Value("${disk.title}") String title, @Value("${disk.artist}") String artist) {

        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
    }
```

**app.properties**

```
disc.title=New Songs
disc.artist=Illayarajah
```

I have written the above code to autowire the fields. But I am getting below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autowireDemo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.springinaction.autowiring.BlankDisk com.springinaction.autowiring.AutowireDemo.blankDisk; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'disk.title' in string value "${disk.title}"
```

Can anyone please suggest why I am getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still get the exception after changing the spelling mistake, please make sure if you have added `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` on top of the configuration class

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I found the error to be in the discrepancies between my `src/main/resources/application.properties`

`src/test/resources/application.properties`
The property I was trying to inject was not in the latter file and when SpringBoot tried to run the test as part of the build, it could not find the property.